# What is wrong with my Silverlight / WCF Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight

I've been struggling for a few hours I admit. I must be missing something with the Bindings/Configuration between my Silverlight application and WCF web service. It was working for awhile, but I must have accidentally changed some settings and I can't get it to work anymore.

In Visual Studio when I debug I have both the Service and Silverlight application launch at the same time, I have Windows authentication disabled in the web.config files for debugging. When I deploy, I go back and change my Configuration files to enable Windows security/transport so I can get user credentials on the web service side.

Now when I deploy both the WCF service and the Silverlight application to a different machine using IIS, I get an error "Not Found" from Silverlight when it attempts to contact the WCF service. Could someone explain to me the different configuration files that exist and what each should be pointing to? Here are my configuration files in their respective locations:

wwwroot\webserviceapp\web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WebserviceName.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
      name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="WebserviceName.IService1">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

wwwroot\web.config - this is the web.config for silverlight I guess?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                      </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://<<<ip_to_machine>>>/webserviceapp/Service1.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint" 
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="ProjectTestPage.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

wwwwroot\ClientBin\SilverlightApp.xap (the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file):

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://<<<ip_to_machine>>>/webserviceapp/Service1.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint" 
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

These are the three configuration files which seem to drive everything, unless I am wrong? Since I develop on one environment and deploy to another it seems like I must change these files to point to the right resources. When I hit my Silverlight application after I've deployed it to the new machine I get the application loading. Once it finishes loading, the first web service call it makes fails with exception and I get this in the Chrome Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://<<<ip_to_machine>>>/webserviceapp/Service1.svc
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://<<<ip_to_machine>>>/webserviceapp/Service1.svc
Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at Project.ServiceReference1.GetAllNewsCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at Project.View.Home1.ClientGetAllNewsCompleted(Object pSender, GetAllNewsCompletedEventArgs pEventArgs)
   at Project.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.OnGetAllNewsCompleted(Object state)
```

I'm like 99% certain that the Service is NEVER hit. I have a log statement at the very top of the function which is being called and it never logs anything.

IIS Configuration:
Web Service Authentication:
Anonymous = Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation = Disabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled

Default Web Site (where my silverlight app is hosted):
Anonymous = Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation = Disabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled

Anyone have any suggestions, or need anymore information from me to help debug?

EDIT: It is worth noting that I am able to navigate to the service from a different machine and see the service wsdl just fine. For example:

```
http://ipaddress/webserviceapp/Service1.svc
```

I can see this just fine, no errors.

Comment: I didn't read all of that, but have you considered using trace logging or using Fiddler to get more details? See http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2013/04/finding-root-cause-of-wcf-exceptions.html and http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2013/03/inspecting-browser-requests-and-server.html.

Comment: I've went back and enabled trace logging in all of the web.config files, but no log files are ever generated. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Something is wrong with your trace logging setup, or your service is never getting hit. Have you tried Fiddler?

Comment: Ok you forced me to use Fiddler, and it's telling me my exact errors! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pretty simple. The error I was receiving is a very generic error. The proper thing to do in this instance is to use Fiddler which will tell you EXACTLY what the error is. In my case, Trace logging wasn't working properly due to the service not loading properly. However, Fiddler was able to give me the exact exception messages which led me to resolve the problem quickly and easily.